# Having a rich treeview

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, treeview

I need to create an user interface like "**liquid xml studio**" the designer part in c# or something like visual studio class designer interface . I think they are using treeview control but I dont understand how it's possible to have something like expandable groupboxes with other controls inside instead of tree nodes.
Thanks

Comment: Note: You can easily have those with WPF.

Comment: would you please explain more . but liquid xml studio and visual studio doesn't need .net framework 3.0 !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for advanced treeview control, [hstreeview](http://code.google.com/p/hstreeview/) might be your choice.

Comment: it's not possible to add other controls as treenode to this treeview control . this is what I want to create :http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XmlStudio/Free-Xsd-Editor.aspx (the graphical designer) .